# Azure DevOps Boards - Allow users to add Picklist values?

Tags: azure-devops, picklist

AFAIK the picklist values are pre-defined at design time, with an option to allow the user to enter custom values, as seen below.

**Question:**

How can I allow the user-entered value to be remembered/stored so they are available in the future?

**Scenario:**

I define the current customers into the Picklist. New customers are signed up, and my QA team opens ticket and enters "NewCo" into the field. I'd like "NewCo" to be available as a Picklist dropdown item.

*Thanks!*

[image: Definte Picklist Items]
[image: Allow Users to Entger Their Own Value]